# How to make an enemy spawner that selects from a list of potential enemies? (Unity)

Tags: unity

I'm just making a practice version of a basic 2D RPG, but I'm trying to build a spawner kind of object that could be scaleable across the entire game. That is, there would be multiple types of enemies, and each instance of such a spawner would have a specific set of enemies that it would spawn.

I'm sure the answer is very simple, but I'm at the beginning stages of all of this. I guess really I just want a simple list that I can attach to my object and add the enemy names to it so that it can draw from that to figure out what they would spawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is. Simply add a public array of type GameObject and drag and drop your enemy prefabs in it inside the inspector panel. Use Random.Range(x,y) to get a random int and use it this way:

```
r = Random.Range(0, enemyTypes.Length); //random.range normally gives back a float, therefore, you may need to use 1 instead of 0
Instantiate(enemyTypes[r], position, rotation);
```

Hope that was enough & I was able to help you :)